# How to notify a UWP app that its secondary tile has been removed (unpinned) by the user?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

In Windows 10, an app can pin secondary tiles to the start menu.
How is the app notified when the user removes (unpins) such a tile?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the API to see if the tile exists when you need to present information:

```
// Check if the secondary tile is pinned
bool isPinned = SecondaryTile.Exists(tileId);
```

That's all, there is no notification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/secondary-tiles-pinning

Comment: So there is no callback that the user has removed the tile? So if the tile is no longer there, and it should be, I can assume that it has been removed...  huh. 

Thanks